# Importing unnecessary files on index

Tags: javascript, node.js

Which is preferred method  ?

1. import everything a,b,c....z in a index.js file and export it.

   Then do `import {a,b,c} from './folder'`.
2. individually do

```
import a from './folder/a';
import b from './folder/b'; ?
```

Does (1) need more memory as I'm importing a...z but only using a..c ?

If yes, does that matter ?

Comment: In node.js why would you ever import anything into a module that you are not using?

Comment: im using but not in the current file. e.g file A im importing 'e,a,b,c' , file B im importing 'a,c,e,d,z' and so on.

Comment: Are you asking if you should have a file which exports everything so you can import just one module and pick what you want from it? Regardless, that's all up to opinion. Loading things you don't need will end up in longer processing time and more memory usage but if it's more readable and maintainable that way while still being fast/small enough then don't worry about it.

Comment: You should actually learn about node.js. A file **is** a module in node and it has it's own scope. So importing things into a module that you are not going to use is senseless and yes it wastes resources.

Comment: @MikeC yeah thats what im asking. If you look here https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/blob/master/src/index.js they are  exporting everything from index.js. Is this a bad practice ?

Comment: @SlimShady Nah. It's neither good nor bad. It's convenient. Unless you're really just scraping for speed and memory it's usually better to have the convenience over the optimization